# How can I troubleshoot a dead tachometer in a 1998 Toyota Carolla?

Tags: toyota, troubleshooting, corolla, tachometer

My daughter bought a 1998 Carolla with a manual transmission. All the gauges work fine except the tachometer. I used a BlueDriver to get the ODB2 data and it shows the RPMs in live mode (I'm guessing the engine wouldn't run if the ECU didn't know the RPMs). The tachometer doesn't move at all and the small LCD under it is blank.

I've looked at fuse diagrams and I don't believe there is a separate fuse for the tachometer so I think if a fuse was blown then all the gauges would have failed but that blank LCD is very suspicious since it's in the same section as the tachometer.

Does this tach connect to the distributor or is it driven from the ECU? Is there a way to diagnose this without tearing a bunch of stuff apart?

She's learned how to drive the car without the tach so this isn't a critical issue, I just thought it would be nice to get it working for her if possible. Her brother and her cousin want to learn to drive stick so it might be nice for them too.

Comment: More than likely the tach itself is just dead. It should be getting its signal from the ECU, so knowing you're getting a reading from live data should pretty much confirm it to either be the tach itself, or the connection (wiring) between the ECU and the tach. The only other bit of diagnostics you could do (which I can think of) is to check the wiring itself. Someone else may have an 'actual' answer for you, so leaving this as a comment.

Comment: The car I learned to drive manual on was a 1968 VW Bug, and it did not have a tach. Really, when learning to drive manual looking at the tach is diverting the drivers attention from the really useful stuff like the sound of the engine, the feel of the accelerator and clutch, and the overall performance of the vehicle. Perhaps a tach is useful if you happen to have pegged your speedometer and want to actually know how fast you were going, but for learning to drive stick it is an impediment.

Comment: I generally agree @JonCuster, I did view it as something of a benefit that she didn't have the tach and once you know how to drive stick you don't care about it anyway. You make a good point that it could actually be bad because it can distract a learning driver.